# How can I fix these floorboards?

Tags: repair

Two of the pieces of my floorboard are damaged and I'm looking for a way to fix them. I'm kind of lost so what process/steps should I take to repair this?

[image: Damaged floorboards]

Answer (score 1):

Vinyl planks interlock with each other, so unlike wood floors, there's no easy way to remove the broken one and insert a new one (real wood floors are also interlocked, but there are tricks one can use to replace a single board.)

If this is near a wall, you could remove the trim (baseboards), remove that section of the floor, and re-do it replacing the two broken planks with new ones.

You could also cut the planks in two using an oscilating multi-tool, remove them. With a utility knife, remove the interlocking lip on the new and surrounding planks. Glue the new one from the top. This will not look pretty, but just a tad better than the broken planks.

Comment: (Those look more like laminate than LVP.)  OP could also disassemble the floor and hopefully relocate the bad boards to a location under a rug or furniture.

Comment: @Huesmann Agreed. With some luck, they still have some planks saved from the original installation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have appears to be laminate flooring.

It is not real wood, so it cannot be filled and sanded and restained.

Outside of replacing the damaged pieces, the only possible solution may be filling the damaged areas with an epoxy as smoothly as possible and trying to paint some grain onto it to blend.  This may be unacceptable to you, however the  only other option is replacement.

Comment: A disturbing number of homeowners also often choose a 3rd (bad) option: leaving it in place and putting a new cheap floor over it.